# PHP making first letter an image

Tags: php, image, letters

I need an HTML-safe function which will change a first letter of the content to the image source.

So if my content will be: `"Hello World!`" the output will look like:
 `"<img src="/images/letters/H.png" alt="H"/>ello"`

I've tried something like:

```
$content = '<img src="/images/letters/'.$content[0].'.png" />'.substr($content, 1);
```

But I've heard this way isn't safe for HTML due to characters like `<` and `>`.

Comment: Sorry but a bit offtopic: can't you use @font-face?

Comment: Why isn't this "safe" enough?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Who said it wasn't safe and why?

Comment: @PeeHaa Hehe, sure I can but those letters are strongly edited in Photoshop and I won't be able then to reach a similar effect in CSS.

Comment: Why it's not safe - well, sometimes, the $content will contain html characters like <, >, ", etc. then I won't be able to handle those characters, same as my native letters like ĄŚĆŹŻĘ (Ofcourse I won't use them, just in case if they'll occur).

Comment: It's safe. Just remember first character of title may not be a letter(or digit) and that URI's are case-sensitive. And add `alt` and `title` attributes to `img` tag.

Comment: Then just enumerate them and make the image name a number. Also, you should be using css sprites for something like this. Chances are, however, your customers really don't care how fancy your letters look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$content = '<img src="/images/letters/'.$content[0].'.png" />'.substr($content, 1);
```

will work just fine, it will always be truncated to 1 character, so as long as you have no sensitive files in that directory named _.png or something, you're fine. To ensure your page doesn't break:

```
$alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
if (strpos($alph,$content[0])) {
    $content = '<img src="/images/letters/'.$content[0].'.png" />'.substr($content, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = preg_replace("/^([a-z])/i","<img src=\"/images/letters/$1.png\" alt=\"$1\" />",$content);
```

Comment: Btw. how the content should look like? Because it's not working for me atm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about creating a broken image? How about:

```
$first_letter = $content[0];
// A <= $first_letter <= Z
if(('A' <= $first_letter ) && ($first_letter <= 'Z')) {
    $content = '<img src="/images/letters/' . $first_letter . '.png" />'.substr($content, 1); 
}
```